# Same APNS token for multiple devices with same Apple ID

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have a strange case with APNS.
A user has two devices with the same Apple ID and our app installed. Both devices return the same APNS token to my app.

Whenever I try to send a push notification, the older device receives it, though we want the newer device (the one that the app was installed to recently) to receive it.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I use multiple devices with the same Apple ID and I've never seen this, are you storing the token somewhere (like in iCloud) so it's being synchronized between devices instead of using the token you receive in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`?

Comment: that scenario is highly unlikely as APNs generates [_globally-unique device tokens_](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html) – it must not be the same on different devices, even the same device generates different device token for the same app after you'd re-install the app; where is your device-token coming from? aren't you registering every device individually?

Comment: How do you registering for Push Notifications and generate device token? Could you provide your code?

Comment: Have you tested with multiple devices and users? Does it happen all the time? Or just for one user? For real testing, you can use facebook app to log same user in 2 devices and send push notifications and check what FB does.

Comment: Are you using your apple_id as a primary key on database table containing the push keys. because maybe that's what's causing your bug. one apple id may have multiple push keys wherein one push key should not have multiple apple ids.

Comment: Plase expand a little, we aren't able to help you without any more information.

Comment: It's not possible to have same APNS token for different devices even though user is logged in with same apple id on both devices. It depends on cryptographic certificate and cryptographic private key that each device has.

Comment: Do you have a definitive way of knowing the tokens generated on those devices? If they are in fact the same, then it might be a bug in iOS or with the APNS service.

Comment: Are you absolute certain that there is not a flaw in you implementation of storing token and sending pushes?